# Why does the following exponent fail in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, exponent

I am using Fortran 77, the g77 compiler.

I have the following.

```
program title
implicit none
real*4 x,y

y=2
x = (y-4)**.7

end program
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. If I do: `-2^0.7` it works, but not if I do `(-2)**.7`. Why is that? I only ask because I am writing a program where y is a variable and it will go below 4, so I can't just write `-2^0.7`

Thanks!

Comment: Because you can't raise a negative number to a fractional power and still get a real number.

Comment: *so I can't just write* `-2^0.7`. Indeed not, that would not be Fortran.

Comment: Also, `-2**.7` does not equal `(-2)**.7` ;-)

Comment: (y-4)*abs(y-4)**(.7-1) ?? what are you trying to do?